# Python regexp find non-repeated statement in source code

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have source code like the following, which by assumption is perfectly syntactically valid:

```
MyType basket("woven"); // initialize statement

double x = 0; // miscellaneous code

MyType bucket("plastic") ; // another initialize statement

for(int i=0; i<324; ++i ) { cout << i << "\n"; }

/* example of a disposal statement */
MyType basket();
```

What I want to do is detect the statement `MyType bucket("plastic");` because there is no subsequent corresponding `MyType bucket();` statement.

Using Python, I constructed the following regular expression (using both the `DOTALL` and `MULTILINE` options). But there's a problem, and I don't know what it is.

```
(?P<stmt>MyType\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\(\s*"|'[^"']+"|'\s*\)\s*;[^(?P=stmt)]*$
```

---

Essentially, I need to know how to use a named group (like `(?P=stmt>)`) and check for repeats of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one:

```
(MyType\s+(\S+)\([^)]+\)\s*;)(?!.*MyType\s+\2\(\s*\)\s*;)
```

Here is the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/zR2tR4/23)

Answer (score 2):

```
MyType\s*(\w+)\S+\s*;(?!.*?MyType\s*\1)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zR2tR4/20